# Java. Вытащить из файла последнюю строку, выполнить с ней операции, результат записать в виде новой строки

Tags: java

Товарищи, нужна помощь в реализации следующего:
есть текстовый файл со строкой в виде

```
числоА1;ЧислоБ1;ЧислоВ1;ЧислоГ1
```

или через пробел/запятую(но лучше не запятую, т.к. числа дробные)

Затем, либо через интерфейс, либо через консоль, я должен ввести по порядку

```
ЧислоА2, ЧислоБ2, ЧислоВ2, ЧислоГ2
```

Программа должна, например, из `ЧислоА2` вычесть `ЧислоА1`, из `ЧислоБ2` вычесть `ЧислоБ1` и тд.

результаты записать новой строкой, типа

```
ЧислоА3;ЧислоБ3;...
```

Соответственно, при след. обращении к программе, он должен мне дать для расчета последние цифры `ЧислоА3` и тд.

Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Вы пишете, что нужна помощь. Я правильно понимаю, что основную часть работы вы уже сделали? Покажите, что у вас уже есть, и расскажите, чего не хватает.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как вы просите помощи, то я покажу вам основные действия:

1. Считать файл
2. Считать с консоли/интерфейса числа
3. Вывести разность этих чисел

---

**Пункт 1.**
На [enSO показано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635136/read-integers-separated-with-whitespace-into-int-array), как можно записать числа в массив из файла.

```
String[] arr = reader.readLine().split(";");
int[] intarr = new int[arr.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
   intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
```

**Пункт 2.**
Теперь нам надо ввести числа в массив с консоли, пригодится `Scanner`:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[4];
    System.out.println("Введите 4 числа:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

**Пункт 3.**
Вывод:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(intarr[i] - arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.